# Creating layout for chat room in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, chat

I am building a chat client and server using Rails.  I have choosen to use Bootstrap for the front end.  However my HTML and CSS skills are very limited and I am having trouble creating the chat layout, I am aiming for something similar to skype.

Here is a mock of what I am trying to achieve.

[Chat Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjI5F.jpg)

I am trying to get everything to stay at 100% of the browser viewport.  So list of chat messages have an overflow scroll.  I can get the general layout but I can not figure out to keep it all within the viewport.  Could anyone help out with this?

Cheers

Comment: You should check out http://learnlayout.com

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap you will want to declare your navigation bar (fixed-top and nav-bar-collapse) before you declare the two columns necessary for the Chat participants list and the chat display. The body of your page will be similar to col-lg-3 and col-lg-9. Assuming you have bootstrap 3.0 it will be responsive. I do not develop rails applications but in Grails (similar MVC framework for Java) you must also remove the default styles that Grails includes automatically to ensure that Bootstrap is the css styling the page.

An example would be the jumbotron template Bootstrap includes on its page. Leave out the jumbotron and change the column widths for the body and you should get a very similar result to what you are striving towards.

If you really want the page to extend to the page edge, do not include the `div class='container'` on line 77.